# Python script does not work but shell does: Serial read

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am reading data from the serial port and successfully see data using the Shell/IDE. However when I use the same commands in a script from the CLI, the response hangs till I interrupt using the keyboard. I have tried commenting out pieces of the script and narrowed down the problem to the following line: ser.readline().
Any help to resolve this will be very beneficial. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("start")
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(2.0)
ser.readline()
print("end")
```

Comment: This code raises an `IndentationError`. And since this behavior could be caused by an indentation problem (if the `if` is outside the `while`, you'll just loop forever around the `readline` and never do anything with the result), it's important that we're seeing exactly your code.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the shell" and "the CLI"? Usually those refer to the same thing—running Python in a shell (like bash or cmd.exe) in a terminal (like gnome-terminal or… um… the other half of what cmd.exe is). Exactly what circumstances work and what don't?

Comment: you most likely need to break out of your while loop on `EOF` (`Ctrl-d` at the command line)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. The indentation error is because of the way I pasted on to stack overflow. I have it correctly indented. Even this script hangs up when I execute from the CLI:    #!/usr/bin/python
    print("start")
    import serial
    import time
    ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
    time.sleep(2.0)
    ser.readline()

Comment: I tested the code in the IDLE interface provided with RPi. It works. However when I use it in a script, it does not. I commented out the ser.readline() and that executes the script fine.

Comment: BTW I edited the code above and just used the simple version without any loop.

Comment: Problem solved: Had to reinstall and update pyserial.